# how to insert vector element into link with cURL c_str() function in C++?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm working on a c++ code that fetches a variable from a text file and adds it to a fixed url, similarly to the following example:

```
int x = numbers[n];
string url = "http://example.com/" + x;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

but I'm getting this error message after compiling

**Protocol "tp" not supported or disabled in libcurl**

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you know smth about the pointer arithmetic, what does pointer + number? I guess `x` is 2, and `"http://example.com/" + x` results to a pointer to `"tp://example.com/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an `int` to a `const char*` pointer (that was decayed from a string literal of type `const char[20]`).  That will offset the pointer by however many elements the `int` indicates.  Which, in your case, appears to be 2, which is why CURL thinks the URL begins with `tp:` instead of `http:`.

Your code is basically the equivalent of this:

```cpp
const char strliteral[] = "http://example.com/";
...
int x = numbers[n];
const char *p = strliteral;
string url = p + x; // ie: &p[x]
```

```
h t t p : / / e x a m p l e . c o m /
^   ^
|   |
p   p+2
```

To fix that, you can use `std::to_string()` in C++11 and later to convert the `int` to a `string`, eg:

```cpp
string url = "http://example.com/" + to_string(x);
```

Or, you can use a `std::ostringstream` (in all C++ versions), eg:

```cpp
ostringstream oss;
oss << "http://example.com/" << x;
string url = oss.str();
```

Or, you can use `std::format()` in C++20 and later (you can use [the {fmt} library](https://fmt.dev) in earlier versions), eg:

```cpp
string url = format("http://example.com/{}", x);
// or:
string url = format("{}{}", "http://example.com/", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = numbers[n];
string url = "http://example.com/" + x;
```

In c/c++ there is pointer arithmetic.

```
const char* ptr = "abcde";
string s1 = ptr + 0; // "abcde";
string s2 = ptr + 1; // "bcde";
string s3 = ptr + 2; // "cde";
...
```

So your string is wrong.

Please check `to_string()` and `const char* to string` on web.